# Cannot make work exe from python with gspread

Tags: python, python-3.4, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have a script, which uses [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) for manupilating with Google Drive data.
And I want to create a simple executable in Windows. But yet no luck.

**Note**

- Python 3.4
- Windows XP

What I've tried so far:

- PyInstaller 3.0
- py2exe 0.9.9.2
- cx_Freeze

---

1. **PyInstaller**

   Goes to the step **60020 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs** and then

   blah-blah-blah...

   ```
     File "C:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 246, in basename
       return split(p)[1]
     File "C:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 217, in split
       d, p = splitdrive(p)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 161, in splitdrive
       normp = p.replace(_get_altsep(p), sep)
   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'
   ```

---

2. **py2exe**

Setup.py (configuration took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file))

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

- Before I added `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` I was getting `RuntimeError: Maximum recursion depth exceeded.`
- Added `sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)` and `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Error is with mf3 file as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649440/py2exe-runtimeerror-with-tweepy), so I added `"excludes":["six.moves.urllib.parse"]` but error is the same.

---

3. **Cx_Freeze**
   This was the closest to success. Even created exe. But there's a problem with **cacert** with getting `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`
   I've tried all methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157502/requests-library-missing-file-after-cx-freeze) and here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043756/how-do-i-make-calls-to-aws-with-python-3-and-httplib2-on-windows-7), copied cacerts.txt, cacert.pem but still `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Here is a code of **setup.py**:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import requests.certs

includefiles = ['key.json', (requests.certs.where(),'cacert.pem')]
includes = []
excludes = []
icon = None
base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = 'Scraper',
    version = '1.0',

    author = 'GriMel',
    author_email = 'GriefMontana@gmail.com',
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,
                             'include_files':includefiles,
                             'icon' : icon}},
    executables = [Executable('main.py')],
    )
```

Looking forward to you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486631/pyinstaller-compiled-file-has-ssl-issue-error-185090050)
So, step by step

1. Go to C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\httplib2
2. Edit **init**.py
3. Replace

`CA_CERTS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )), "cacerts.txt")`

by

`CA_CERTS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "cacerts.txt")`

4. Run cx_freeze script
5. Search for **cacerts.txt** and **cacert.pem** (in my case *C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\certifi* and *C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\httplib2*
6. Copy **cacerts.txt** and **cacert.pem** to the folder with exe file.
7. PROFIT

At least exe, made by cx_freeze now works.

Comment: This works. I searched solution for days and when this finally solved everything, I had to register to stackoverflow and gain reputation only to give this post an upvote. Thank you!